# return data from two collections with data:function in iron:router Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Not using publish or waitOn or other advanced technique for learning purposes. Somehow I can't get this to work.

```
Router.route('/browse/:_id', function(){
            this.render('navigation', {to: 'navbar'});
            this.render('header', {to: 'header'});
            this.render('website', {
              to: 'main',
              data: function(){
                return {
                    websites: Websites.findOne({_id: this.params._id}),
                    comments: Comments.find({siteId: this.params._id})
                   }
              }
            });
        });
```

This code works great for 'comments' while 'websites' won't render.
The fields under 'websites' will render in HTML only if I return it like this:

```
data: function(){   /*This works for websites but if used on comments it won't*/
         return Websites.findOne({_id: this.params._id})
       }
```

while for 'comments' it only works if I give out in Object notation or key-value pairs:

```
data: function(){   /*This works for comments but if used on websites it wont*/
                return {comments: Comments.find({siteId: this.params._id})}
              }
```

My problem is I need to get data off both collections in the same template. Any suggestion is very much welcome. Thanks!

**Edit** Including my HTML Templates as well: 'website' template

```
<template name="website">
<div class="container">
    /*solved by including #with websites here*/
    <div class="website">
        <div class="website-header js-url">
            <h4>{{title}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="website-body">
            <tr><td>URL:</td> <td>{{url}}</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Description</td><td>{{description}}</td></tr>

            <div class="votes">
                <div class="upvote_row">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Up Votes:</td>
                        <td>{{upVote.length}}<a href="#" class="btn btn-default js-upvote"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                </div>
                <div class="downvote_row">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Down Votes:</td>
                        <td>{{downVote.length}}<a href="#" class="btn btn-default js-downvote"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                </div>
            </div>

            <tr><td>Posted By:</td><td><a href class="">{{createdBy}}</a> on {{createdOn.toDateString}} at {{createdOn.toLocaleTimeString}} </td></tr>              
        </div>
    </div>
    /* /with */
    <div class="comments">
        <h5>Comment Section</h5>
        {{#if currentUser}}
        <a class="btn btn-default js-toggle-comment-form" href>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
        {{/if}} 
        <div id="comment_form" class="hidden_div">
            <form class="js-save-comment-form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="user_comment">Add Comment</label>
                <input type="textfield" class="form-control" id="user_comment" placeholder="Your views on this website" required>
              </div>

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
              <button class="btn btn-default js-cancel-submit">Cancel</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <ol>
        {{#each comments}}
        {{>comment_item}}
        {{/each}}
        </ol>
    </div>

 </div>
</template>
```

Then my comment Template which works flawlessly.

```
<template name="comment_item">
    <li class="card-panel teal darken-1 comments">

        <blockquote>
            <p class='card-content'>
                {{userComment}}
            </p>
            <footer>
                <a href="{{url}}">{{postedBy}}</a> on {{postedOn.toDateString}} at {{postedOn.toLocaleTimeString}}
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default js-upvote">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="badge badge-notify">{{upVote.length}}</span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default js-downvote">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="badge badge-notify">{{downVote.length}}</span>
                </a>
             </footer>
        </blockquote>
    </li>
</template>
```

Comment: Two things: 1.) I would try using a template with the navigation, header, footer, etc. all included in the template, and then render a single template. 2.) I don't know why it's behaving in that way, but it could have something to do with the fact that findOne() will return an object while find() is going to return a cursor. Try using find().fetch() instead maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You should show your HTML template code as well. I suspect that you are referring to keys for the websites object directly instead of using `{{websites.keyname}}`. Based on your data function, your data context will be `{websites: an object, comments: a cursor}` If you try to access `{{keyname}}` from your websites you'll get nothing because your data context doesn't have a top level key called `keyname`.

Comment: Hi, how do we setup that `keyname`? You are correct it had to do on how I was referring to keys on `websites` from my Template. I solved it yesterday already with the same code as above(first one w/ both on), after I included {{with websites}} before I started referring to keys from `websites`

Comment: `keyname` is just whatever top level key(s) you have in a `websites` document. If there's a top level key called `foo` then you'd refer to it with `{{websites.foo}}`